# providing link's to the data in the array of jqBarGraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

hi i'm using corporate clean theme for my drupal site, in that i'm using jqBarGraph plugin where i succeed in getting the graph what i want, but one more thing i want to add in this data is to give links for the them to the content in another page is that possible to give like that, here is the array of data what i used to get the graph in my page:

```
arrayOfData = new Array(
  [32,'66','skyblue'],
  [32,'67','skyblue'],
  [43,'68','skyblue'],
  [131,'69','skyblue'],
  [101,'70','skyblue'],
  [125,'71','skyblue'],
  [62,'72','skyblue'],
  [67,'73','skyblue'],
  [59,'74','skyblue'],
  [95,'75','skyblue'],
  [92,'76','skyblue'],
  [74,'77','skyblue'], 
  [84,'78','skyblue'],
  [66,'79','skyblue']
);
```

here for the middle element i.e, 66, 67,... i want to give links to the data in another page i.e, if i click on 66 it will take me to the data in another page, similarly for 67.... how can i achieve that???

any help is much appreciated..thanks in advance...:)

Comment: You mean that you want to assign click to any bar you want which will lead to to other page?

Comment: yes i can do like that also...can u tell me how can i do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, jqBarGraph doesn't give possibility to set links to bars. You have to write your own javascript code.

Every bar have unique ID. So your javascript code should be similar to:

```
var links = {
  // bar id's                // links
  '#graphField0simpleGraph': 'node/123',
  '#graphField1simpleGraph': 'node/321'
};

for (id in links) {
  $(id).live('click', function() {
    document.location = links[id];
  });
}
```